# What is the function of @this exactly?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

As far as I know the **@this** is to denote the current component triggering the event, such as :

```
<p:commandButton process="@this" ... />
```

And in JSF 2 Ajax, the **@this** can also mean the encapsulating component, like :

```
<h:inputText ...>
  <f:ajax execute="@this" ... />
</h:inputText>
```

And I have one case where using **p:datatable**, including or excluding **@this** can have a different impact upon Ajax partial submit

Here's the example, in this case, the process is using **@this**, and this works as expected, where when process happens first, and then followed by **setPropertyActionListener** and last, the **action** is executed :

```
<p:column>
    <p:commandLink 
        value="#{anggaranDetail.map['code']}"
        process="@this infoAnggaranForm:Anggaran"
        update="detailDialogForm:Anggaran detailDialogForm:SubAnggaran"  
        oncomplete="infoAnggaranDialog.hide()" 
        image="ui-icon ui-icon-search"
        action="#{tInputBean.updateAnggaranSubAnggaran}">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{anggaranDetail}"
            target="#{infoAnggaranBean.selectedAnggaranDetail}" />
    </p:commandLink>
</p:column>
```

But when I omit the **@this** from this example, the **setPropertyActionListener** and the **action** are never executed, as if they're not there.

I wonder why ? Perhaps **@this** has some other meaning other than the current component, perhaps the current record in this example ?

Im using tomcat 7, and these are my dependencies :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4-b09</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4-b09</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The PrimeFaces `process` and standard JSF `execute` attributes should point to spaceseparated component identifiers of components which JSF should process during the entire JSF lifecycle upon an ajax request (get request parameters, validate them, update model, execute action). The `process` defaults to `@form`, the current form, and the `execute` defaults to `@this`, the current component. In command links/buttons this is mandatory to execute the actions associated with the link/button itself.

However, in your datatable you have `process="@this infoAnggaranForm:Anggaran"`, thus two components to process. If you omit `@this` but keep the other component, then it will only process/execute the other component and not the link/button component. If you omit the `process` attribute it will default to `@form`. If you have more other input components in the same form, then they will also be processed.

Depending on the concrete functional requirement, you could just keep it `process="@this infoAnggaranForm:Anggaran"`, or omit it. JSF will then process/execute at least both the button and the other component, exactly as you want.

#### See also:

- [Understanding PrimeFaces process/update and JSF f:ajax execute/render attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-process-and-update-attributes-of-primefaces/)

Comment: In command links/buttons this is mandatory to execute the actions associated with the link/button itself. <-- ahhhhh, this is new to me, and enlightening. Thank you ! About the **process** attribute of primefaces tags, i think it defaults to @all based on my tests. And as you said already, **execute** defaults to @this. Thanks again BalusC !