# Temporarily disable JSF validations

Tags: validation, jsf

A has many required inputs and validations. A couple of command buttons control different inputs.

I can change required attibrute with the value of `<f:param>`. For instance when a button is clicked,it sets a value.This value changes if an input is required or not. Like this:

```
<p:commandButton>
        <f:param name="button1" value="1"></f:param>
        </p:commandButton>

        <h:inputText required="#{param['button1'] == 1}"></h:inputText>
```

This actually works.However i also want to add some valitations like max length.I want to temporarily change this validation too.

I tried to disable valitadion,but i did not work:

```
<f:validateLength  disabled="true" maximum="10"></f:validateLength>
```

Comment: The `validateLength` facet essentially uses a pre-built Validator class in the JSF implementation, which JSF implementation are you using? It also typically runs validation during the Validation phase. Does putting the attribute `immediate="true"` on the commandButton change the results at all?  Try implementing the [BalusC Debug Phase LifeCycle Listener](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html) and at each of the phases check the properties of the length validator on your InputText UIComponent.  This may lead to some interesting clues.

Comment: Another suggestion would be to set the `maximum` attribute to some inordinately large number and see if that works.  I would do that as a last resort though as it seems like a hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using JSF 2.x already. So just use `<f:ajax execute>` or `<p:commandButton process>` to specify client IDs of components which are to be executed/processed when the button is pressed. All components which are not included in this will just be ignored and not converted/validated.

E.g.

```
<h:inputText id="input1" ... required="true" />
<h:inputText id="input2" ... required="true" />
<h:inputText id="input3" ... required="true" />
<h:inputText id="input4" ... required="true" />

<p:commandButton value="Submit inputs 1 and 2" process="input1 input2" ... />
<p:commandButton value="Submit inputs 3 and 4" process="input3 input4" ... />
```

In case of `<p:commandButton>` it defaults to `@form` (i.e. the entire current form).

#### See also:

- [Understanding PrimeFaces process/update and JSF f:ajax execute/render attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-process-and-update-attributes-of-primefaces/)

Comment: This is a great mechanism, but it should be noted that it is specific to Primefaces, ie p:commandButton .  Correct?

Comment: @eugenevd: Nope. As answered, in standard JSF you can use `<f:ajax execute>` for this.

Comment: @ BalusC Ha! Just spotted that at http://stackoverflow.com/a/5704558/831750 - Thanks :)