# ajax="false" vs process="@this"

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm get confused with this 2 concepts `ajax="false"` and `process="@this"`. Is the resulting view the same?, is there any order of execution?, will both execute the validation phase? something else should I care about?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ajax="false"` means that your `UICommand` e.g. `<p:commandButton>` will perform a request/response process without using ajax. This is an attribute for PrimeFaces `UICommand`s.

`process="@this"` means that only the current component value will be send to the server instead of sending the data from the whole `<h:form>`. This attribute belongs to PrimeFaces components that have ajax functionality embedded. It is similar to `execute` attribue in [`<f:ajax>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html) from JSF.

More info:

- [What is the function of @this exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5699088/1065197)